# const T* vs typedef

Tags: c++, syntax

The following code doesn't compile for me in visual studio 2012:

```
//1. Define struct
struct TestList
{
...
};

//2 define a pointer to 1. struct as typedef
typedef TestList * TestListPtr;

//3. use it latter on in the code as follows:
    const TestList* p1 = 0;
    const TestListPtr p2 = p1;
```

Then, get this compile error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const TestList *' to 'const TestListPtr'
```

An reason why the above can be considered illegal syntax?

Haven't tried it with other compilers yet.

Comment: `const TestList*` this is a pointer to a const TestList, `const TestListPtr` this is a const pointer to a TestList. The compiler won't let you go from `const T` to `T` without a `const_cast` (or a C-cast *shudders*)

Comment: Note: const Testlist* is a mutable pointer with immutable content, const TestlistPtr is a immutable pointer  with mutable content.

Comment: Some fun reading on this subject: http://www.drdobbs.com/conversationsa-midsummer-nights-madness/184403835

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is right, all conformant compilers must reject that. The reason is that the declarations group differently:

`const TestList * p1` declares `p1` to be a pointer to a constant `TestList`.

`const TestListPtr p2` declares `p2` to be a constant `TestListPtr`. `TestListPtr` is a pointer to (non-constant) `TestList`. Spelling out `p2` without the typedef is this:

```
TestList * const p2 = p1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one place where the syntax of the language is not intuitive.

```
int const i;
```

is the same as

```
const int i;
```

When you mix pointers, there are four possible options:

```
int* p1;               // You can modify both p1 and *p1
int const* p2;         // You can modify p2 but not *p2
int* const p3;         // You can not modify p3 but can modify *p3
int const* const p3;   // You can not modify p4 or *p4
```

Unfortunately, you can write

```
int const* p2;
```

as

```
const int* p2;
```

also, which is the source of your confusion.

Instead of using

```
const TestListPtr p2 = p1;
```

if you use

```
TestListPtr const p2 = p1;
```

it is clear which part of `p2` is constant. It would be clear that `p2` cannot be modified but `*p2` can.